# ExpiresByType not working for PNG images when set in .htaccess for a WordPress site

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, css, page-speed, cache-control

In my website I have the expires headers settings reported below. When I use Google's PageSpeed Insights test I get the message: `XYZ.png expire headers not set`, which I'm getting for all the PNG files in the WordPress theme I'm using.

It looks to me like PNG expires headers are already set in the *.htaccess* file, but I'm still getting this error/warning.

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType image/png .png
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to set the PNG expires headers correctly?

Comment: If you examine the HTTP response headers yourself, what do you see?

Comment: Is mod_expires enabled?  On my Ubuntu/Debian system I can run `sudo a2enmod expires` to enable it.

Comment: I also prefer to use "access plus 8 hours" rather than A31536000 because it is so much more readable.

Comment: `A31536000` == `access plus 1 year`

Comment: I had a curious issue where if I had a comment (preceded by a hash symbol) on the same line, it would cause an error 500. Make sure comments are on their own line